# IndentationError: expected an indented block 10

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, indentation

Here is the code

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(2, GPIO.IN)


while True:
  if GPIO.input(2) == False:
print ("marshmallow makes a good input")
  time.sleep(0.5)



File "marshmallow.py" , line 11
   print ("marshmallow makes a good input")
       ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

I got this code from a book and I'm not sure what's wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The code in an `if` block (or any block for that matter) must be indented further than the statement that opens the block. In this context, that means your code should look like this:

```
while True:
  if GPIO.input(2) == False:
    print ("marshmallow makes a good input")
  time.sleep(0.5)
```

Or perhaps like this:

```
while True:
  if GPIO.input(2) == False:
    print ("marshmallow makes a good input")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

From the code you've posted, it's not entirely clear which of these two you want (though it's probably the former - you probably want to be sleeping at each loop iteration).

Note also that in Python code, it is preferred that each level of indentation consist of 4 spaces, not 2 - so *ideally*, this code would look like this:

```
while True:
    if GPIO.input(2) == False:
        print ("marshmallow makes a good input")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    if GPIO.input(2):
        print ("marshmallow makes a good input")
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Python uses [indentation to group statements](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming).
The if-statement requires a statement (or statements) indented underneath. The `print` statement gets executed if `GPIO.input(2)` is Truthy.

---

Note that `if GPIO.input(2) == False` is not considered Pythonic. The usual way of writing this is

```
if not GPIO.input(2):
```

Comment: The code is supposed to do nothing when false and print "marshmallow makes a good input" when true, but thanks anyway